# How to group/total data from mySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in the database that I want to perform a mySQL query on. Here's what the table looks like:

**https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At5_g34zSM41dFlNWUdNQnRPandiUUFuaUJzTEc1REE&usp=sharing**

Given this table, I want to display the total number/count of users per journey and goalname.

I've tried to use GROUP BY and COUNT but what I only get is this:

[image]

As you can see, the data is only grouped by goalname. Is there a way where I could achieve this kind of result through mySQL query:? (see image below)

[image]

Something like this. I hope you could help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to `PIVOT` the columns into rows. Unfortunately, MySQL has no `PIVOT` table operator. But you can use the `CASE` expression to do this, like -

```
SELECT
  journey,
  SUM(CASE WHEN  goalname = 'Frank.net Hospital Cash Back' THEN count END) AS `Frank.net Hospital Cash Back`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN  goalname = 'Frank.net Life Cover' THEN count END) AS `Frank.net Life Cover`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN  goalname = 'Frank.net Salary Protection' THEN count END) AS `Frank.net Salary Protection`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN  goalname = 'King Price Car Insurance' THEN count END) AS `King Price Car Insurance`
FROM test
GROUP BY journey;
```

SQLFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/314c6/8

Comment: +1 Great mind think alike.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just modified the query to fit my needs. I replaced the sum with COUNT. :)

Answer (score 0):

Below query might work in your case.

```
SELECT 
a.journey, 
a.goalname, 
FIND_IN_SET(a.goalname, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(goalname) FROM <table_name> b.journey =  a.journey)) AS no_of_goalname
FROM <table_name> a
```

Answer (score 0):

you've already accepted an answer, but just for fun, if you wanted to dynamically generate the column names, so that if new entries of `goalName` are entered you don't have to change your code you can use the below ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0d196/2/0))

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  getCount//
CREATE PROCEDURE getCount ()
BEGIN
  -- First we declare all the variables we will need
  DECLARE loopGoalName VARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE dynamicSql VARCHAR(5000);
  DECLARE finalSql VARCHAR(5000);
  -- flag which will be set to true, when cursor reaches end of table
  DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN;         

  -- Declare the sql for the cursor
  DECLARE example_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT goalName
    FROM YourTableName;

  -- Let mysql set exit_loop to true, if there are no more rows to iterate
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;
  SET dynamicSql = '';
  SET finalSql = '';
  -- open the cursor
  OPEN example_cursor;

  -- marks the beginning of the loop
  example_loop: LOOP

    -- read the name from next row into the variable l_name
    FETCH  example_cursor INTO loopGoalName;
    -- check if the exit_loop flag has been set by mysql, 
    -- if it has been set we close the cursor and exit 
    -- the loop
    IF exit_loop THEN
        CLOSE example_cursor;
        LEAVE example_loop;
    END IF;
    SET DynamicSql = CONCAT(DynamicSql,",SUM(IF(goalName='",loopGoalName,"',1,0)) as `",loopGoalName,"`");
  END LOOP example_loop;
  SET finalSql = CONCAT('SELECT journey',DynamicSql,
                         ' FROM yourTableName
                           GROUP BY journey');
  -- now we run set some variables and run the dynamically built query
  SET @finalSql = finalSql;
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @finalSql;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
END//
```